# How would kinetic bombardment look like on impact to an observer on Earth's surface?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics, observers

To be clear, I do want to know this because on the Worldbuilding Stack Exchange's chat room and on the Discord servers I am in, I have been told conflicting accounts about how such bombardment would look like to an observer.

Assumptions are as follows:

We have a 2 stage kinetic rod which is 20 meters long and 2 meters in diameter, with a first stage to deorbit from a 1,500 km altitude above the Earth's surface, accelerate to a terminal velocity of Mach 25 from an 80 km altitude using the remaining delta v from a fusion thermal rocket engine, which gives me ~11 kt of TNT equivalent on impact. From there, the engine stage separates and the main rod speeds towards its target.

The problem? How would that look like to an observer on the ground and what would happen on impact?

Bonus points if the observer is in a major metropolitan area of 1,000,000 or more inhabitants, just for good measure.

WARNING: I am unsure if this is the place for this kind of question. You have been warned.

Comment: -1 Not clear what you are asking. What do you mean by "What would this look like?" Are you asking how many buildings would be destroyed and how many people killed? If so, this is off topic, as it depends on too many factors beyond the scope of physics. If not, please identify what is your question about physics?

Comment: Hiroshima and Nagasaki were about 20kt: it would look like that (with some preceding bright line in the sky as it came in).

Comment: So like what happened in [GI Joe: Retaliation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jOKf5r_JMAo)? (see also the [Reel Physics](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BTYOc8b776E) discussion on it).

Comment: @KyleKanos. Except more realistic, and not.......well, handwavium.

Answer (score 1):

The question is somewhat underconstrained because we do not know how streamlined the rod is. There will be supersonic shock heating of air. The naively calculated [adiabatic stagnation temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stagnation_temperature) at Mach 25 is about 126 times ambient temperature (~300 K), 37,800 K. This model is obviously not right at this speed, so I think we are talking about temperatures merely around 3,000-6,000 K ([this is the figure from actual meteorite impacts](https://leonid.arc.nasa.gov/AST119.pdf)). Somewhat obviously the rod will be very bright on descent. However, were it streamlined enough the plasma will likely be more dispersed - it will not be so much a point but a long trail.

In any case, given the speed of about 8.5 km/s and an assumed 90 degree angle it will basically descend from the stratosphere within a second, becoming brighter as it approaches the ground.

The effect will be somewhat different from a normal meteorite impact since the impactor is elongated (and a bit higher density than a normal iron meteorite), but a rough estimate can be done using the formulas in [the Earth impact effects program](https://www.purdue.edu/impactearth/Content/pdf/Documentation.pdf) ([graphical version](http://simulator.down2earth.eu/planet.html?lang=en-US)). Basically it is a pretty tiny impactor: using their formula for crater size $D\approx 1.161 (\rho_i/\rho_t)^{1/3} L^{0.78} v_i^{0.44} g^{-0.22} \sin^{1/3}\theta$ with $\rho_i/\rho_t=6.9$, $L=7.8$ (i.e. converting the cylinder into a sphere), $v_i=8.5$ km/s, $g=9.82$ and $\theta=\pi/2$ gives $D\approx 356$ meters.

Since the impactor is elongated and hypersonic it will continue according to [Newton's approximation of impact depth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impact_depth#Newton.27s_approximation_for_the_impact_depth), $L\rho_i/\rho_t
 \approx 142$ meters.

So the actual effect will be a bright (color may range between red to actinic white depending on size and temperature of the plasma in front of it) line descending over a span of less than a second. It will penetrate the ground fairly deep, and there release its kinetic and thermal energy as a pretty powerful explosion. Since it is so fast and deep the thermal effects are negligible (in fact, there won't be a fireball since the speed is a bit too low): it will be all about a pressure wave, although there will presumably be a bit of a mushroom cloud afterward. The seismic effects will likely be bigger than the impact program predicts because more energy gets deposited deep, but the exact change is beyond me. Overall, the effects are going to be a major earthquake and likely a lot ejecta - like parts of buildings - flying through the region. The crater will likely be smaller and initially deeper than the above calculation since the penetration is deep, but will soon start to fill out as the rim avalanches in.

As a final note, from a military standpoint this might be a reasonable futuristic bunker-buster. But as a weapon of mass destruction against a city it is over-engineered compared to a vanilla fusion warhead. Also, if it was faster it would be far more damaging: the classic orbital kinetic missile really suffers from the limitations imposed by deorbiting.

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted to know for reasons I will leave to the Worldbuilding SErs to solve. :P Oh and I forgot to mention: it is practically a cylindrical object, with a cone at the tip, though I am not sure if that is practical. At all. :/